# How to avoid special character from URL using java

Tags: java, urlencode, urldecode

I am using below code to eliminate the special characters from URL:

```
String url1 = "https://dev/ABC/v1/XYZ?itemnumber%255Bin%255D=%255B3001%252C3005%252C202%255D&limit=2&apikey=4zVYEk2Xg8zvwYxNnW&offset=2";

String decodedURL = URLDecoder.decode(url1, "UTF-8");

System.out.println(decodedURL);
```

Expected output:

> https://dev/ABC/v1/XYZ?itemnumber[in]=[3001,3005,20]&limit=2&offset=1&apikey=4zVYEk2Xg8zvwYxNnW

Error output:

> https://dev/ABC/v1/XYZ?itemnumber%5Bin%5D=%5B3001%2C3005%2C202%5D&limit=2&apikey=4zVYEk2Xg8zvwYxNnW&offset=1

Comment: Why would you expect `offset=1` when your input ends with `offset=2`?

Comment: typo error ,now its corrected

Comment: it still says `offset=2` in the code snippet. Also, the API key differs.

Answer (score 2):

Your string is double-URL encoded, see https://ideone.com/CQQbPz:

```
String url1 = "https://dev/ABC/v1/XYZ?itemnumber%255Bin%255D=%255B3001%252C3005%252C202%255D&limit=2&apikey=4zVYEk2Xg8zvwYxNnW&offset=2";

System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(url1, "UTF-8"));
System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.decode(url1, "UTF-8"), "UTF-8"));
```

Output:

```
https://dev/ABC/v1/XYZ?itemnumber%5Bin%5D=%5B3001%2C3005%2C202%5D&limit=2&apikey=4zVYEk2Xg8zvwYxNnW&offset=2
https://dev/ABC/v1/XYZ?itemnumber[in]=[3001,3005,202]&limit=2&apikey=4zVYEk2Xg8zvwYxNnW&offset=2
```

Answer (score -4):

Browsers and many other http programs convert illegitimate url request symbols to URL encoding scheme that place a % percent sign in front of two numerals. Before use, use

```
String decoded = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(request);
```

Comment: The question shows that URLDecoder.decode is already being used.